# Vertical-align/Valign not working

Tags: html, css

Basically, i'm making a newsletter for a company and i need the "Schrijf reactie" button to be in the middle, but vertical-align and valign aren't working and using media queries for top/bottom is not an option.

```html
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    
        <style type="text/css">
         .ReadMsgBody {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
         .ExternalClass {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
         body  {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-family: Georgia, Times, serif}
         table {border-collapse: collapse;}
        
         @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {
             .deviceWidth {width:440px!important; padding:0;}
             .center {text-align: center!important;}
           }
        
         @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
             .deviceWidth {width:280px!important; padding:0;}
             .center {text-align: center!important;}
           }
    
    </style>

</head>

    <body>
    
    <table bgcolor="#4275A2" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" style="margin:0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:10px 0;">                          
                <table align="left" width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px; color: white; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 24px; padding:10px 8px 10px 8px">
                            <h2 style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;font-size:18px;color:white;">Schrijf uw bevindingen ook eens in ons gastenboek. Dat stellen wij, en andere klanten zeer op prijs.
                         <br/><br/></h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="veritcal-align:bottom;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#542841" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                            <a href="#" style="border-radius: 5px;padding: 20px;color:#ffffff;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;display:block;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">SCHRIJF REACTIE</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
                
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use flexbox? This would be easier with divs rather than a table.

Comment: `<table style="veritcal-align:bottom;"` - if spelling it right doesn’t fix your problem ... then please properly explain what the problem actually is. [ask], [mcve]

Comment: Please correct your speeling of **veritcal**  **TO** **vertical**

Comment: @Leander this appears to be an e-mail template. You don't want to use css rules that were introduced after Napoleon Bonaparte died in e-mail templates...

Comment: source without meaning for this problem should be removed to make the question easier to read (next time please).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vertical-align` property will not apply on *nested table elements which have no containing table-cells of their own* to maintain the typical tabular structure of a table. 
Columns should be kept equal in height for the `vertical-align` property to result in the expected behaviour, you will require table-cells to do this.

Consider nesting your `table` elements in separated table cells (`td`) which you can then declare a `vertical-align` property value on:

**rather this:**

```
<!-- better approach -->
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> <!-- now you can declare a vertical-align property -->
         <table></table>
      </td>
      <td> <!-- now you can declare a vertical-align property -->
         <table></table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**instead of this:**

```
<!-- wrong approach -->
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table></table>
         <table></table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```html
<table bgcolor="#4275A2" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:10px 0;vertical-align: middle;width: 70%;">
      <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 12px; color: white; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 24px; padding:10px 8px 10px 8px">
            <h2 style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;font-size:18px;color:white;">Schrijf uw bevindingen ook eens in ons gastenboek. Dat stellen wij, en andere klanten zeer op prijs.
              <br/><br/></h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="padding:10px 0;vertical-align: middle;">
      <table style="veritcal-align:bottom;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#542841" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;">
            <a href="#" style="border-radius: 5px;padding: 20px;color:#ffffff;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;display:block;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">SCHRIJF REACTIE</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```